# Load images async in SwiftUI with DispatchQueue

Tags: image, asynchronous, swiftui

I created a home view with three navigationlinks. With a click, a view appears with a List of 180 images, fetched from AWS S3. During scrolling, the view is hitching. Therefore the images shall load in background async.  I already implemented a downsample-function for reducing the memory footprint. I followed the talk from [WWDC 2018](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/219/), which explains how to implement async loading using DispatchQueue. But I don't get it to work.
BTW, I'm pretty new to SwiftUI and Swift.

I tried to implement it like in this screenshot from the WWDC talk. My implementation is commented in my own code snippet below.
[image: Screenshot]
I also tried to work with the Combine framework, but didn't find a solution for my problem.
Most websites describe how to work with DispatchQueue in Swift, but not in SwiftUI, what makes it difficult for me where to start off.

```swift
var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(range.count, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: ImageLargeView()) {
                    //DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    Image(uiImage: downsample(thisReturnesAllDownsampledImagesAsUIImage))
                    //}
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 200, alignment: .center)
                .clipped()
            }
        }
}
```

My aim is to get rid of the hitching behaviour with a minimum of memory footprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at some blog posts about asynchronous image loading in SwiftUI. [This one](https://medium.com/@azamsharp/asynchronously-loading-images-in-swiftui-3d0452230949) for instance looks like it describes the technique you need to use perfectly.

In a nutshell: put a custom View in your hierarchy that handles downloading on a background thread and then updates the image when the view has been downloaded.

There are Cocoapods available as well, like [this one](https://github.com/dmytro-anokhin/url-image) for instance.

Comment: Wow, the link is perfect. I tried SDWebImageSwiftUI and SwURL, but urlImage sounds pretty perfect. Even if I wished to get something to work with, to understand the functionality in the background.